# PL/SQL cursor that skip rows recording in database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I can`t understand why cursor that I have in my procedure
skip rows.
Here is my cursor:

```
OPEN c_denormalized_data FOR lv_sql_str;
    LOOP
 FETCH c_denormalized_data
   INTO r_denormalized_data;
 EXIT WHEN c_denormalized_data%NOTFOUND;

 INSERT INTO bpdev.bp_real_to_fiskal_reference
   (r_customer_trx_id,
    r_trx_number,
    r_trx_date,
    r_amount,
    r_amount_due_rem,
    diff,
    f_trx_number,
    f_trx_date,
    f_amount,
    NULLS,
    notnulls,
    org_id,
    data_loaded_for_days)
 VALUES
   (r_denormalized_data.r_customer_trx_id,
    r_denormalized_data.r_trx_number,
    r_denormalized_data.r_trx_date,
    r_denormalized_data.r_amount,
    r_denormalized_data.r_amount_due_rem,
    r_denormalized_data.diff,
    r_denormalized_data.f_trx_number,
    r_denormalized_data.f_trx_date,
    r_denormalized_data.f_amount,
    r_denormalized_data.nulls,
    r_denormalized_data.notnulls,
    r_denormalized_data.org_id,
    days_before_today);
 COMMIT;   
   END LOOP;
```

**lv_sql_str** is dynamic SELECT the execution of which takes about 30 min. 
The cursor is used because this select is dynamically generated based on the input parameters.
If I execute only a SELECT statement I receive all data that I expect, but when I execute procedure to insert in database I losе records
that appear in the data returned by my SELECT.
I can't understand why these records are skipped and are not inserted in the table.
Does anyone have an idea where my mistake is?

Here is my full code:

```
PROCEDURE load_denormalized_data(errbuf                      OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2,
                               retcode                     OUT NOCOPY NUMBER,
                               days_before_today           IN NUMBER,
                               real_legal_entyties_id_list IN VARCHAR2) IS
TYPE tc_denormalized_data IS REF CURSOR;
c_denormalized_data tc_denormalized_data;
TYPE tr_denormalized_data IS RECORD(
  r_customer_trx_id bpdev.bp_real_to_fiskal_reference.r_customer_trx_id%TYPE,
  r_trx_number      bpdev.bp_real_to_fiskal_reference.r_trx_number%TYPE,
  r_trx_date        bpdev.bp_real_to_fiskal_reference.r_trx_date%TYPE,
  r_amount          bpdev.bp_real_to_fiskal_reference.r_amount%TYPE,
  r_amount_due_rem  bpdev.bp_real_to_fiskal_reference.r_amount_due_rem%TYPE,
  diff              bpdev.bp_real_to_fiskal_reference.diff%TYPE,
  f_trx_number      bpdev.bp_real_to_fiskal_reference.f_trx_number%TYPE,
  f_trx_date        bpdev.bp_real_to_fiskal_reference.f_trx_date%TYPE,
  f_amount          bpdev.bp_real_to_fiskal_reference.f_amount%TYPE,
  NULLS             bpdev.bp_real_to_fiskal_reference.nulls%TYPE,
  notnulls          bpdev.bp_real_to_fiskal_reference.notnulls%TYPE,
  org_id            bpdev.bp_real_to_fiskal_reference.org_id%TYPE);

r_denormalized_data tr_denormalized_data;
lv_where_le_ids     VARCHAR2(3000);
lv_sql_str          VARCHAR2(5000);
 BEGIN
bpdev.bp_utils.put_log('>>>--------ПОТРЕБИТЕЛСКИ СЪОБЩЕНИЯ--------<<<');
bpdev.bp_utils.put_log('Изтриване на старите данни.');
DELETE bpdev.bp_real_to_fiskal_reference rfr;
COMMIT;


lv_where_le_ids := bp_utils.set_where_clause('invr.org_id',
                                             real_legal_entyties_id_list,
                                             ',',
                                             ';',
                                             0);
lv_sql_str      :=     
 'SELECT invr.customer_trx_id r_customer_trx_id,
   invr.trx_number r_trx_number,
   invr.trx_date r_trx_date,
   round(invr.extended_amount, 2) r_amount,
   round(nvl(ps.amount_due_remaining, invr.extended_amount), 2) r_amount_due_rem,
   round(invr.amount_without_credits - invf.extended_amount, 3) diff,
   invf.trx_number f_trx_number,
   invf.trx_date f_trx_date,
   round(invf.extended_amount, 2) f_amount,
   round(invr.extended_amount +
         nvl((SELECT SUM(psa.amount_credited)
               FROM ar_payment_schedules_all psa
              WHERE psa.customer_trx_id = invr.customer_trx_id),
             0) - invf.extended_amount,
         1) NULLS,
   round(nvl(ps.amount_due_remaining, (invr.extended_amount * 1.2)), 2) notnulls,
   invr.org_id
FROM (SELECT cth.customer_trx_id,
           cth.trx_number,
           cth.trx_date,
           SUM(ctl.extended_amount) * 1.2 extended_amount,
           round(((SUM(ctl.extended_amount) * 1.2 +
                 nvl((SELECT SUM(psa.amount_credited)
                         FROM ar_payment_schedules_all psa
                        WHERE psa.customer_trx_id = cth.customer_trx_id),
                       0))),
                 2) amount_without_credits,
           cth.org_id,
           nvl(decode(TRIM(ctl.interface_line_attribute13),
                      0,
                      NULL,
                      TRIM(ctl.interface_line_attribute13)),
               cth.interface_header_attribute13) interface_line_attribute13
      FROM ra_customer_trx_all       cth,
           ra_customer_trx_lines_all ctl
     WHERE cth.customer_trx_id = ctl.customer_trx_id AND
           ctl.line_type = ''LINE'' AND
           ctl.set_of_books_id = 1001
          GROUP BY cth.customer_trx_id,
              cth.trx_number,
              cth.trx_date,
              cth.org_id,
              nvl(decode(TRIM(ctl.interface_line_attribute13),
                         0,
                         NULL,
                         TRIM(ctl.interface_line_attribute13)),
                  cth.interface_header_attribute13)) invr,
   (SELECT cth.customer_trx_id,
           cth.trx_number,
           cth.trx_date,
           SUM(ctl.extended_amount) * 1.2 extended_amount,
           round(((SUM(ctl.extended_amount) * 1.2 +
                 nvl((SELECT SUM(psa.amount_credited)
                         FROM ar_payment_schedules_all psa
                        WHERE psa.customer_trx_id = cth.customer_trx_id),
                       0))),
                 2) amount_without_credits,
           cth.org_id,
           nvl(decode(TRIM(ctl.interface_line_attribute13),
                      0,
                      NULL,
                      TRIM(ctl.interface_line_attribute13)),
               cth.interface_header_attribute13) interface_line_attribute13
      FROM ra_customer_trx_all       cth,
           ra_customer_trx_lines_all ctl
     WHERE cth.customer_trx_id = ctl.customer_trx_id AND
           ctl.line_type = ''LINE'' AND
           cth.set_of_books_id = 2001
     GROUP BY cth.customer_trx_id,
              cth.trx_number,
              cth.trx_date,
              cth.org_id,
              nvl(decode(TRIM(ctl.interface_line_attribute13),
                         0,
                         NULL,
                         TRIM(ctl.interface_line_attribute13)),
                  cth.interface_header_attribute13)) invf,
   ar_payment_schedules_all ps
    WHERE invf.interface_line_attribute13(+) = invr.customer_trx_id AND
   ps.customer_trx_id(+) = invr.customer_trx_id AND
   invr.trx_date >= SYSDATE - ' ||
                   days_before_today || ' ' || lv_where_le_ids;

bpdev.bp_utils.put_log('Зареждане на новите данни.');
OPEN c_denormalized_data FOR lv_sql_str;
LOOP
  FETCH c_denormalized_data
    INTO r_denormalized_data;
  EXIT WHEN c_denormalized_data%NOTFOUND;

  INSERT INTO bpdev.bp_real_to_fiskal_reference
    (r_customer_trx_id,
     r_trx_number,
     r_trx_date,
     r_amount,
     r_amount_due_rem,
     diff,
     f_trx_number,
     f_trx_date,
     f_amount,
     NULLS,
     notnulls,
     org_id,
     data_loaded_for_days)
  VALUES
    (r_denormalized_data.r_customer_trx_id,
     r_denormalized_data.r_trx_number,
     r_denormalized_data.r_trx_date,
     r_denormalized_data.r_amount,
     r_denormalized_data.r_amount_due_rem,
     r_denormalized_data.diff,
     r_denormalized_data.f_trx_number,
     r_denormalized_data.f_trx_date,
     r_denormalized_data.f_amount,
     r_denormalized_data.nulls,
     r_denormalized_data.notnulls,
     r_denormalized_data.org_id,
     days_before_today);
END LOOP;
COMMIT;
CLOSE c_denormalized_data;
bpdev.bp_utils.put_log('>>>------КРАЙ ПОТРЕБИТЕЛСКИ СЪОБЩЕНИЯ-----<<<');
 EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  bpdev.bp_utils.put_log(retcode || errbuf);
    END load_denormalized_data;
```

Comment: why dont you debug it ?

Comment: We can't see the cursor, the data, the parameters, what you run manually, or if you're accessing the same tables in the same schema - and whether all data is committed.  You haven't given any indication of how many rows are expected and how many are missing, or whether there's any common pattern is those that seem to be skipped. Why are you using a cursor loop (and committing every row!?) instead of a dynamic `insert ... select` to insert all of the rows at once?

Comment: There does not seem to be any logical mistake in your code. However, you have not posted your full code. Few points: 1) Have you coded an exception section where you are handling and skipping exceptions. 2) Have you tried printing lv_sql_str in your procedure and then executing the query in SQL and see if you are getting all the records.

Comment: I tried to debug, but my select returns over 10 000 entries, so it limited the only one who is not saved when execute the procedure. When put this restriction row is recorded without any problems.

Comment: I'm not sure what that comment means. You still need to identify which rows are being skipped and see what they have in common. As you have no upper restriction on `trx_date` is data being added (or updated/deleted) between when you run this and when you run the query? What does `set_where_clause` do? Are you running *exactly* what the dynamic SQL looks like with that generated clause and verifying `lv_where_le_ids ` is what you expect? (You could avoid doing this dynamically, but that's a side issue...)

Comment: are you sure this is returning correct data ? `lv_where_le_ids` , maybe your problem is here , `invr.trx_date >= SYSDATE - ' ||  days_before_today || ' ' || lv_where_le_ids` put  the value you expect as static then try

Comment: Also if `trx_date` has times other than midnight a later run may exclude rows an earlier one found; using `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` would avoid that possibility. As well as possibly including rows more rows from today - you have a moving window. But that comes back to finding a pattern in what (if anything) is missing, and we can't do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

we dont have all info , but I suspect the problem is here

```
 invr.trx_date >= SYSDATE - ' ||        days_before_today || ' ' || lv_where_le_ids;
```

try to add the date you expect as static then try again.